# Is it a good idea to use neo4j with Redis?

Tags: redis, neo4j, dataset, neo4j-apoc

I have the data of around **623G** (nodes and relationships) in a csv which is consuming around **670G** to cache all the data. Hence we are running the system of **94 cores and 750G** of memory on cloud. My intention here is to reduce the system config, but with the same dataset. Is it possible to use `redis` here or do I have to think of any other method like `splitting the data into multiple smaller instances` ?

Comment: You might want to shard your data.

Comment: Agree with Charchit, you should check https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/

Comment: Great, thanks. So, Redis is not the better option in this case, is it right ? @CharchitKapoor @ oLDo

Comment: No, Redis is not intended for these large datasets.

Comment: Did you consider using RedisGraph, this way you won't need both Neo4J and Redis

Comment: No, didn't explore RedisGraph yet. @GuyKorland

Comment: Can RedisGraph handle this huge data ? @GuyKorland

Comment: it can handle huge graphs and it saves the graph topology in a very efficient way based on sparse matrix